# How do I push an entire project to a specific folder in one of my GitHub repositories?

Tags: git, github

I already have a repository on my GitHub with a Swift project in it. I have a different local repository with an Objective-C project, and I want to push that local repository inside an empty folder called "Objective-C", which is inside my Swift GitHub repository.

In the end, I should have my Swift GitHub repository with my local Objective-C project files inside the empty "Objective-C" folder of the Swift GitHub repository.

I know how to push my project to my GitHub, but that will create a new repository, and I don't want that. How can I push an entire project to a specific folder without creating a new project?

Comment: You add the files of the project to the folder, you git add them, you commit, and you push. Or am I misunderstanding something in your question?

Comment: Was this resolved? You should be able to add the files and then the repos will be nested. What exactly are you trying to avoid? Are you trying to merge them into one repo?

Comment: I think I need a little more information about what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want them to be in the same repo, or different? Are you merging projects or just files from another project?

Comment: @DougMead I want my local Objective-C project to be in the repo of the github swift project, specifically: in the empty "Objective-C" folder I created in the swift github repo.

Comment: You should be able to just copy and paste it, then push the original repo. I'm sorry, it seems like I'm missing what the issue is.

Comment: @DougMead You were absolutely right ! Once I donwloaded the github desktop app that day, I realised the solution was actually that simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do `git pull` to synchronise your repository with the online one
2. You copy the folder of the project you want into your local copy of your GitHub repository.
3. You do a commit with `git commit -c "Whatever you want here"`
4. Execute a `git push` to synchronise repositories.

Comment: Sry, but you misunderstood my question I think. I already have a repo on my github with the swift project in it. I have a different local repo with the objective-C project and I want to push that local repo inside a folder called "Objective-C" that is inside my swift gihub repo.

Comment: You cannot put a git repo inside another like that. You would need to create a second repo on Github to hold your code, or just simple transfer the files to the Swift project. And great both as a single project with different folders. My procedure up there still applies to this case. Note that you will loose all commit history on the Obj-C code when you transfer it to the Swift Repo. It will be as a new commit to that one